# Two's complement of a std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl, logical-operators, twos-complement

I am trying to convert a std_logic_vector in its two's complement. I am trying to perform -2 multiplication on a vector.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity twoscomplement is 
port ( x : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
       y : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
      );
end entity;

architecture model of twoscomplement is 
signal x_c : std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);

x_c <= (not(x) +'1')*2 ; -- x_c = -2*x

end model;
```

Comment: And what is your specific question? Do you have errors you need to deal with?

Comment: You're missing a `begin` after the signal x_c declaration. For earlier than -2008 with an added use clause of `use ieee.numeric_std.all;`, `x_c <= std_logic_vector(shift_left(not unsigned(x) + 1, 1));`, where the shift left a distance 1 will have a result length matching x. For -2008 a use clause of `use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;` and `x_c <= shift_left((not x + 1), 1);`. Using "*" will increase the result length. See Guide to use of standard packages IEEE Std 1076-2008 G.3.5.1 Multiplication by a power of 2 with remaindering,

Comment: Don't take the 2's complement of a `std_logic_vector`. Take the 2's complement of a `numeric_std.signed`.

Answer (score 0):

add library

```
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
```

... inside architecture

```
x_c <= signed(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting to integers and work with them.

Check out this webpage on conversions. 
visit http://www.bitweenie.com/listings/vhdl-type-conversion/